# Enyo JS Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Tags: javascript, enyo

How do I keep focus within a grid or view ?

Using the arrows keys or the emulator remote if I go too far left, right, up, or down I lose focus.

I've tried spotlight : 'container' , but that does not seem to work.

Stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null dom.js:353
enyo.dom.getAbsoluteBounds dom.js:353
enyo.kind.getAbsoluteBounds Control.js:662
_calculateNearestNeighbor enyo.Spotlight.NearestNeighbor.js:170
getNearestPointerNeighbor enyo.Spotlight.NearestNeighbor.js:200
_spotNearestToPointer enyo.Spotlight.js:262
onKeyDown enyo.Spotlight.js:485
onEvent enyo.Spotlight.js:311
(anonymous function) enyo.Spotlight.js:799
enyo.dispatcher.dispatch dispatcher.js:73
enyo.dispatch
```

Any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modified dom.js and that seem to have done the trick.

```
 var width          = 0; //node.offsetWidth;
 var height         = 0; //node.offsetHeight

            if(node){
                var width          = node.offsetWidth;
                var height         = node.offsetHeight
            }
```

Comment: If you have to do this then you're having problems elsewhere in your code.  You should not need to do this.  Which version of Enyo are you using?